# TWISTED python - Wait for deferToThread to complete

Tags: python-2.7, deferred, twisted.internet

I am new to Twisted framework, and I would like to make the program wait for the deferred thread to complete.

```
import time
from twisted.internet import defer, threads

a=None
def proc(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    print "Hi!!"
    a=1
    return 

d = threads.deferToThread(proc,5)
while not a:
    pass
print a
print "Done"
```

Is it possible to wait for the deferred to complete in a neat way rather than looping like this?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want by deferring to a thread:

```
import time
from twisted.internet import threads, reactor

def proc(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    print "Hi!!"

d = threads.deferToThread(proc, 5)
d.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

To do what you want asynchronously, which is how Twisted is designed, you could do:

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

def say_hi():
    print 'Hi'

d = task.deferLater(reactor, 5, say_hi)
d.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

which is considerably neater and doesn't use any threads. In both cases you have to take care of stopping the event loop (`reactor`) once your function has finished (that's what the `reactor.stop()` callback is for), otherwise your program will just block.